# How to center a ionic button inside an ionic column

Tags: css, ionic4

I want to center the ionic button inside the column.Please help me in doing this.

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>

<ion-col size="6"  ><ion-button >Button 1</ion-button>
</ion-col >

<ion-col size="6"  > <ion-button> button 2</ion-button>
</ion-col>


</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Now the button 1 is towards right. and button 2 is towards left
The expected result is button is in center in each column.[image]

The expected output is as follows

```
..............................................................................
.             button1                   .                   button2
.                                       .
.                                       .
.                                       .
.                                       .
.
..............................................................................
```

When i applied some styles and examined i found it like this

```
 <ion-grid style="background-color:red">
 <ion-row style="background-color:blue;">
    <ion-col size="6" style="background-color:green;"  class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-button>Button 1</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="6" class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-button> button 2</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

The image to be like this..

[image]

Why is the grid not occupying the full browser area.

Comment: In my project looking good and responsive, have you added any extra CSS and check-in mobile view

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

Solution-1:

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="6" class="button1">
        <ion-button>Button 1</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="6" class="button2">
        <ion-button> button 2</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

.button1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.button2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Solution-2:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="6" class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-button>Button 1</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="6" class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-button> button 2</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

[image]

Let me know if it is won't work.

Comment: Sorry
I am not getting as expected.I am getting one button to the right of first column and second button to the left of second column.I want them to be at center.I have included the expected result.

Comment: Please check now!

Comment: I am not getting as expected

Comment: If your problem is solved then, please mark as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Ionic has a range of helper classes for formatting the content. In your case I think this should work:

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="6" class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-button>Button 1</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="6" class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-button>Button 2</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

If that doesn't work then I would investigate the flex classes. You can see them all here:

[CSS Utilities - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities)

## Update

Based on your updated feedback it seems the problem is actually with your `ion-grid` not the buttons or cols. As per the [responsive grid documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/grid):

> Grids take up the full width of their container, but adding the fixed attribute will specify the width per screen size.

So changing your `ion-grid` to:

`<ion-grid fixed>`

Might improve things but it does not explain why you are experiencing this in the first place.

Please use the devtools and inspect the ion-grid to see what styles are affecting it.

Did you start your project with the standard cli tooling? (If not you might be missing stylesheets) -- from the css utilities docs:

> If your app was not started using an available Ionic Framework starter, the stylesheets listed in the optional section of the global stylesheets will need to be included in order for these styles to work.

Did you start the page with a normal layout? I don't see a header so is your page content in an `ion-content`? Don't know how this will affect things without testing but just trying to get to the bottom of why you are not getting the normal Ionic experience...

Comment: it is not working.can you please give the code snippet with flex class

Comment: I think it is working and centered but as you have shown, the grid is only as wide as its content. I've updated my answer.